# Can string concatenation be used for application yml value that includes SpEL?

Tags: spring, spring-el, applicationcontext

I'm trying to define a spring data source url like so:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:${vcap.services.compose-for-mysql.credentials.uri}?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true"
    username: ${vcap.services.compose-for-mysql.credentials.username}
    password: ${vcap.services.compose-for-mysql.credentials.password}
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Where `vcap.services.compose-for-mysql.credentials.uri` is set to `mysql://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx.1.dblayer.com:28018/compose`.

I need the url to look like this:

`jdbc:mysql://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx.1.dblayer.com:28018/compose?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true`

However, Spring doesn't appear to be able to handle this:

> Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@6c6efbc8 returned null for URL:jdbc:${vcap.services.compose-for-mysql.credentials.uri}?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true

Is there a way that I can construct the url using a yaml file, or do I need to use another approach such as xml configuration?

---

*Update*

I've tried:

`url: ${'jdbc:'}${vcap.services.compose-for-mysql.credentials.uri}{'?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true'}`

But get the error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'`

Also tried:

`url: jdbc:${vcap.services.compose-for-mysql.credentials.uri}?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true`

But get the error:

`Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@567443ab returned null for URL:jdbc:${vcap.services.compose-for-mysql.credentials.uri}?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true`

Comment: Is the `vcap.services...` values inside the same property file?

Comment: No, spring boot creates this value from an environment variable

Comment: Try `${env:vcap.service...}`

Comment: results in `Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@54a388b returned null for URL:jdbc:vcap.services.compose-for-mysql.credentials.uri?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true`

Comment: Maybe `${sys:vcap.service...}` but that would not make sense since it is for system properties and not environment variables...

Comment: same issue here any news?

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? I just tested this with 2.5.5 and it works for me. I can set `url: "jdbc:${url}?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true"` in aplication.yml and run my app with `URL=db.example.com ./mvnw spring-boot:run` and it'll print `jdbc:db.example.com?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true`. Similar post where it's also working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911958/1585136

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate your env property with a string value

```
some:
  property: ${envVar}abc
```

In your case

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:${vcap.services.compose-for-mysql.credentials.uri}?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true
```