# How to read variable or concatenate one property in @Value annotation of spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, annotations

I have one POJO class which read properties from application.yaml file in spring boot. Here I need to set default value to groupId(to get when not given) based on combination of topic value and another string.

```
private String topic;

 @Value("${topic}_test")
 private String groupId;
```

I tried this but getting error as

> Could not resolve placeholder 'topic' in value "${topic}_test

I create a variable and tried to access it in @Value but failed.
Please provide any suggestion to access this

Comment: Do you have @ConfigurationProperties at class? For more info see e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Comment: Yes i have given that annotation

Answer (score 12):

#### Default value

Let's say you have a property like this in your application.yml file

```
topic: myFavoriteTopic
```

The code below will assign the value "myFavoriteTopic" to variable `groupId` if Spring is able to load the property with key `topic` from application.yml. If it's not, it will assign the **default value** "my default topic".

```
@Value("${topic:my default topic}")
private String groupId;
```

To set `null` as the default value, use:

```
@Value("${topic:#{null}}")
```

To use an empty String as the default value, use:

```
@Value("${topic:}")
```

#### Get key name from a variable

In your code snippet you have a `String topic` variable. For the Spring framework, this variable is **not used** in the property value retrieval. When you do `@Value("${topic}")`, "topic" is the name of the key that Spring will look for in application.yml. The name of the key cannot be determined at runtime based on the value of a Java variable. The reason is that properties can be loaded before the class code executes.

#### _test suffix

Also in your code snippet, you use `@Value("${topic}_test")`. What Spring does in this case is to concatenate "_test" to the value retrieved for property key topic. In my first example, `groupId` would be assigned "myFavoriteTopic_test".